# Marshal load a marshal dumped instance of a subclass of an Hash

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling

I can't manage to `Marshal.load` a `Marshal.dump`ed instance of subclass of an Hash:

```
class MarshalDumpableHash < Hash

  def initialize(constructor = {})
    if constructor.is_a?(Hash)
      super()
      update(constructor)
    else
      super(constructor)
    end
  end

  def marshal_dump
    p self
    self
  end

  def marshal_load(hash)
    p hash
    update(hash)
  end

end


h = { asd: 'ciao' }

p MarshalDumpableHash.new(h) #=> {:asd=>"ciao"}
p Marshal.dump(MarshalDumpableHash.new(h)) #=> "\x04\bU:\x18MarshalDumpableHash@\x00"

p Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(MarshalDumpableHash.new(h))) #=> {} WHY?
```

It sounds strange to me that the `p self` inside the `marshal_dump` method prints `{:asd=>"ciao"}`, while the one inside the `marshal_load` method prints `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method `marshal_dump` returning `self` is not a usecase for using `marshal_dump`and `marshal_load`, since the built-in dumping and loading does that. So if you just want to marshal `self`, you do not have to write any customized `marshal_dump` or `marshal_load`.

```
class Subclassed < Hash
end

s = Subclassed.new
s[:foo] = :bar
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(s)).class #=> Subclassed
```

These methods are for usecases when you do have surplus information on the object you do not want to reload when loading a dumped object. This is in order to save space. For Example:

```
class Subclassed < Hash

  attr_reader :surplus_info

  def initialize(surplus_info)
    @surplus_info = surplus_info
  end

  def marshal_dump
    Hash.new.merge(self)
  end

  def marshal_load other
    update(other)
  end
end
```

Without the `marshal_dump` and the `marshal_load`, the resulting marshalled string will be:

```
"\004\bIC:\017Subclassed{\006:\bfoo:\bbar\006:\022@surplus_info\"\bfoo"
```

Which has the surplus info. With the marshal load and dump, you will be able to reduce the marshaled string:

```
"\004\bIU:\017Subclassed{\006:\bfoo:\bbar\000"
```

This is the purpose of these methods. Also, the [ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Marshal.html#method-c-load) states:

> marshal_dump may result in smaller Marshal strings.

Also, the doc is a bit vague about using `marshal_dump`:

> When dumping an object the method marshal_dump will be called. marshal_dump must return a result containing the information necessary for marshal_load to reconstitute the object. The result can be any object.

It should maybe read "The result can be any object besides `self`". What I do not know if the behaviour ruby shows when returning `self` in `marshal_dump` is really intentional (At least an error would be nice), or if it just got forgotten since it is not really a usecase.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that returning `self` inside `marshal_dump` could be a problem... thank you

Comment: Since you seem to know a bit about marshalling can you help me with my case? I need to customize marshal load a bit but can't change marshal dump. It's crucial for me that the dump result stays the same as if there was no customization. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717336/how-to-customize-rubys-marshal-load-without-changing-format